# core-plot 2.2 not working for device, works on simulator

Tags: ios, core-plot, ios10

I am attempting to upgrade a project to iOS10. I am using CorePlot 2.2 for this, as it seems to be the branch that will support iOS10 and fix the issues brought up by the OS upgrade. I am having issues with the CorePlot library though, so I wanted to see if the examples even worked. I get the same error when running the examples. An excerpt of the errors is as follows:

```
ProcessPCH /Users/jim.beam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CorePlotExamples-azemopdccaqiyrddoaxvhssxtbip/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/CorePlot_Prefix-aadijwdizyzbyuaimjggfwrpdreq/CorePlot_Prefix.pch.pch CorePlot_Prefix.pch normal arm64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.analyzer\
    cd /Users/jim.beam/Downloads/core-plot-release-2.2/framework\
    export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII\
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"\
    /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c-header -arch arm64 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=c99 -fobjc-arc -gmodules -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -fno-common -Werror -Werror=incompatible-pointer-types -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wmissing-field-initializers -Wmissing-prototypes -Wdocumentation -Wunreachable-code-aggressive -Wnullable-to-nonnull-conversion -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wobjc-missing-property-synthesis -Warc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wexplicit-ownership-type -Wimplicit-retain-self -Wduplicate-method-match -Wmissing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wunused-label -Wunused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wconditional-uninitialized -Wunknown-pragmas -Wshadow -Wfour-char-constants -Wconversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wassign-enum -Wsign-compare -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wnewline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wdeprecated-implementations -DDEBUG=1 -DOBJC_OLD_DISPATCH_PROTOTYPES=0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -miphoneos-version-min=8.0 -g -Wsign-conversion -Wno-infinite-recursion -fembed-bitcode-marker -D__clang_analyzer__ -Xclang -analyzer-output=plist-multi-file -Xclang -analyzer-config -Xclang path-diagnostics-alternate=true -Xclang -analyzer-config -Xclang report-in-main-source-file=true -Xclang -analyzer-config -Xclang mode=shallow -Xclang -analyzer-checker -Xclang optin.osx.cocoa.localizability.NonLocalizedStringChecker -Xclang -analyzer-checker -Xclang optin.osx.cocoa.localizability.EmptyLocalizationContextChecker -Xclang -analyzer-checker -Xclang security.FloatLoopCounter -Xclang -analyzer-checker -Xclang security.insecureAPI.UncheckedReturn -Xclang -analyzer-checker -Xclang security.insecureAPI.getpw -Xclang -analyzer-checker -Xclang security.insecureAPI.gets -Xclang -analyzer-checker -Xclang security.insecureAPI.mkstemp -Xclang -analyzer-checker -Xclang security.insecureAPI.mktemp -Xclang -analyzer-checker -Xclang security.insecureAPI.rand -Xclang -analyzer-checker -Xclang security.insecureAPI.strcpy -Xclang -analyzer-checker -Xclang security.insecureAPI.vfork -I/Users/jim.beam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CorePlotExamples-azemopdccaqiyrddoaxvhssxtbip/Build/Intermediates/CorePlot.build/Debug-iphoneos/CorePlot\\ iOS.build/CorePlot.hmap -I/Users/jim.beam/Downloads/core-plot-release-2.2/framework/Source -I/Users/jim.beam/Downloads/core-plot-release-2.2/framework/iPhoneOnly -I/Users/jim.beam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CorePlotExamples-azemopdccaqiyrddoaxvhssxtbip/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/include -I/Users/jim.beam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CorePlotExamples-azemopdccaqiyrddoaxvhssxtbip/Build/Intermediates/CorePlot.build/Debug-iphoneos/CorePlot\\ iOS.build/DerivedSources/arm64 -I/Users/jim.beam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CorePlotExamples-azemopdccaqiyrddoaxvhssxtbip/Build/Intermediates/CorePlot.build/Debug-iphoneos/CorePlot\\ iOS.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/jim.beam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CorePlotExamples-azemopdccaqiyrddoaxvhssxtbip/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -Weverything -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-undef -Wno-switch-enum -Wno-float-equal -Wno-padded -Wno-dollar-in-identifier-extension -Wno-custom-atomic-properties -Wno-gnu -Wno-assign-enum -Wno-pedantic -Wno-documentation -Wno-unknown-warning-option -Wno-cstring-format-directive -Wno-documentation-unknown-command -Wno-reserved-id-macro -Wno-incompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers -Wno-partial-availability -MD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/jim.beam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CorePlotExamples-azemopdccaqiyrddoaxvhssxtbip/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/CorePlot_Prefix-aadijwdizyzbyuaimjggfwrpdreq/CorePlot_Prefix.pch.d -c /Users/jim.beam/Downloads/core-plot-release-2.2/framework/CorePlot_Prefix.pch -o /Users/jim.beam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CorePlotExamples-azemopdccaqiyrddoaxvhssxtbip/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/CorePlot_Prefix-aadijwdizyzbyuaimjggfwrpdreq/CorePlot_Prefix.pch.pch\
\
In file included from /Users/jim.beam/Downloads/core-plot-release-2.2/framework/CorePlot_Prefix.pch:12:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:12:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccessibility.h:14:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccessibilityAdditions.h:10:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIPickerView.h:10:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIView.h:9:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/QuartzCore.h:9:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CoreAnimation.h:14:\
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CAAnimation.h:18:27: error: cannot find protocol declaration for 'CAMediaTiming'\
    <NSCoding, NSCopying, CAMediaTiming, CAAction>\
                          ^\
In file included from /Users/jim.beam/Downloads/core-plot-release-2.2/framework/CorePlot_Prefix.pch:12:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:12:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccessibility.h:14:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccessibilityAdditions.h:10:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIPickerView.h:10:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIView.h:9:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/QuartzCore.h:9:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CoreAnimation.h:16:\
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CAEAGLLayer.h:17:26: error: cannot find interface declaration for 'CALayer', superclass of 'CAEAGLLayer'\
@interface CAEAGLLayer : CALayer <EAGLDrawable>\
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   ^\
In file included from /Users/jim.beam/Downloads/core-plot-release-2.2/framework/CorePlot_Prefix.pch:12:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:12:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccessibility.h:14:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccessibilityAdditions.h:10:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIPickerView.h:10:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIView.h:9:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/QuartzCore.h:9:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CoreAnimation.h:17:\
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CAMetalLayer.h:44:27: error: cannot find interface declaration for 'CALayer', superclass of 'CAMetalLayer'\
@interface CAMetalLayer : CALayer\
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   ^\
In file included from /Users/jim.beam/Downloads/core-plot-release-2.2/framework/CorePlot_Prefix.pch:12:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:12:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccessibility.h:14:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccessibilityAdditions.h:10:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIPickerView.h:10:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIView.h:9:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/QuartzCore.h:9:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CoreAnimation.h:19:\
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CAEmitterCell.h:11:48: error: cannot find protocol declaration for 'CAMediaTiming'\
@interface CAEmitterCell : NSObject <NSCoding, CAMediaTiming>\
                                               ^\
In file included from /Users/jim.beam/Downloads/core-plot-release-2.2/framework/CorePlot_Prefix.pch:12:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:12:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccessibility.h:14:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccessibilityAdditions.h:10:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIPickerView.h:10:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIView.h:9:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/QuartzCore.h:9:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CoreAnimation.h:20:\
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CAEmitterLayer.h:24:29: error: cannot find interface declaration for 'CALayer', superclass of 'CAEmitterLayer'\
@interface CAEmitterLayer : CALayer\
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   ^\
In file included from /Users/jim.beam/Downloads/core-plot-release-2.2/framework/CorePlot_Prefix.pch:12:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:12:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccessibility.h:14:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccessibilityAdditions.h:10:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIPickerView.h:10:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIView.h:9:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/QuartzCore.h:9:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CoreAnimation.h:21:\
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CAGradientLayer.h:15:30: error: cannot find interface declaration for 'CALayer', superclass of 'CAGradientLayer'\
@interface CAGradientLayer : CALayer\
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   ^\
In file included from /Users/jim.beam/Downloads/core-plot-release-2.2/framework/CorePlot_Prefix.pch:12:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:12:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccessibility.h:14:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccessibilityAdditions.h:10:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIPickerView.h:10:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIView.h:9:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/QuartzCore.h:9:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CoreAnimation.h:25:\
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CAReplicatorLayer.h:19:32: error: cannot find interface declaration for 'CALayer', superclass of 'CAReplicatorLayer'\
@interface CAReplicatorLayer : CALayer\
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   ^\
In file included from /Users/jim.beam/Downloads/core-plot-release-2.2/framework/CorePlot_Prefix.pch:12:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:12:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccessibility.h:14:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccessibilityAdditions.h:10:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIPickerView.h:10:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIView.h:9:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/QuartzCore.h:9:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CoreAnimation.h:26:\
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CAScrollLayer.h:11:28: error: cannot find interface declaration for 'CALayer', superclass of 'CAScrollLayer'\
@interface CAScrollLayer : CALayer\
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   ^\
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CAScrollLayer.h:28:12: error: cannot find interface declaration for 'CALayer'\
@interface CALayer (CALayerScrolling)\
           ^\
In file included from /Users/jim.beam/Downloads/core-plot-release-2.2/framework/CorePlot_Prefix.pch:12:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:12:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccessibility.h:14:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccessibilityAdditions.h:10:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIPickerView.h:10:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIView.h:9:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/QuartzCore.h:9:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CoreAnimation.h:27:\
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CAShapeLayer.h:34:27: error: cannot find interface declaration for 'CALayer', superclass of 'CAShapeLayer'\
@interface CAShapeLayer : CALayer\
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   ^\
In file included from /Users/jim.beam/Downloads/core-plot-release-2.2/framework/CorePlot_Prefix.pch:12:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:12:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccessibility.h:14:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccessibilityAdditions.h:10:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIPickerView.h:10:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIView.h:9:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/QuartzCore.h:9:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CoreAnimation.h:28:\
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CATextLayer.h:15:26: error: cannot find interface declaration for 'CALayer', superclass of 'CATextLayer'\
@interface CATextLayer : CALayer\
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   ^\
In file included from /Users/jim.beam/Downloads/core-plot-release-2.2/framework/CorePlot_Prefix.pch:12:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:12:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccessibility.h:14:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccessibilityAdditions.h:10:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIPickerView.h:10:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIView.h:9:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/QuartzCore.h:9:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CoreAnimation.h:29:\
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CATiledLayer.h:30:27: error: cannot find interface declaration for 'CALayer', superclass of 'CATiledLayer'\
@interface CATiledLayer : CALayer\
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   ^\
In file included from /Users/jim.beam/Downloads/core-plot-release-2.2/framework/CorePlot_Prefix.pch:12:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:12:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccessibility.h:14:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccessibilityAdditions.h:10:\
In file included from /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIPickerView.h:10:\
```

... and it finishes with ...

```
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIView.h:137:176: error: cannot find protocol declaration for 'CALayerDelegate'\
NS_CLASS_AVAILABLE_IOS(2_0) @interface UIView : UIResponder <NSCoding, UIAppearance, UIAppearanceContainer, UIDynamicItem, UITraitEnvironment, UICoordinateSpace, UIFocusItem, CALayerDelegate>\
                                                                                                                                                                               ^\
14 errors generated.\
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. I've spent a lot of time trying to get this fixed. It appears to be a QuartzCore framework issue for the device, but I've verified that QuartzCore and Accelerate are both included everywhere they are needed. I also do not see any errors in the pre-compiled headers file for CorePlot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a clean build of the app to rebuild the precompiled headers. If that doesn't work, also delete the derived data folder to force a rebuild.

Comment: Ah I hadn't thought about the derived data. Not sure how I forgot that. I'll give it a shot. I did a lot of clean and builds though, and even removed the repo from my machine and redownloaded it. But it seems like Xcode recognizes its the same project and uses the derived data. I'll post back after I check that. Thanks!

Comment: Deleting the derived data does not fix the issue. Upon rebuilding, the same errors are presented :-(

Comment: Did you also clean the Core Plot framework files? The error is in the Core Plot precompiled header.

Comment: I tried switching the target to "Universal iOS Framework", "Universal Library", "CorePlot iOS" framework, and "CorePlot-CocoaTouch" library and performed a clean and build on each. The same 14 errors are presented for each. When I deleted the Derived Data earlier, I deleted it for all projects, so I don't think there could have been anything left behind. I really appreciate the help by the way!

Comment: Which Xcode beta are you using? The latest code on the `release-2.2` branch builds for me with Xcode 8 beta 5.

Comment: Did you attempt to build to a physical device or the generic build-only device? Those are the only two that don't work for me. It'll build and run on the simulators. If the physical device is working for you, at least that gives me the sanity check of knowing the branch is good and I can be confident it's an issue with my machine. Maybe I'll try removing and re-installing the Xcode beta.

Comment: Both simulator and device builds work for me. I fixed a minor issue with 32-bit builds yesterday, but that's unrelated to the problem you're seeing. Can you build an iOS app that doesn't use Core Plot with the same copy of Xcode? All of the Core Animation classes and protocols it can't find are part of the QuartzCore framework.

Comment: Interesting, there you go. I just added QuartzCore framework and a reference to CALayer to a project that does not have it. It immediately broke with 15 issues. The same 15 issues as I am seeing in CorePlot. So it does seem that my QuartzCore framework is somehow corrupted. I have deleted and redownloaded Xcode 8 beta 4 twice, and upgraded to Xcode 8 beta 5 though, and continue to see the issue. Do you know of any other way to force my Xcode to redownload a clean copy of the framework? Or maybe deleting Xcode does not remove the framework files?

Comment: As you can see from the paths in the error messages, all of the SDKs are part of the Xcode application bundle. I don't know what to suggest other than reinstalling Xcode, but you already did that.

Comment: I redownloaded Xcode 8 beta 5 last night at home, and everything works now. I know I updated from beta 4 to beta 5 and the issue persisted a couple weeks back when beta 5 was released, so not sure how it was corrupted both times. But anyway, completely deleting Xcode 8 beta from my machine, and redownloading it fixed the problem. Thank You @eric for all of the suggestions and patience helping me out!